Specify startup probe option: gcloud beta run deploy
I have a cloud build pipeline which builds and tries to deploy a multi-container service on Cloud Run.
The containers are:

Frontend (exposed port 3000)
Backend

I specified in the cloudbuild.yaml that frontend depends on backend:
    args:
      - beta
      - run
      - deploy
      - $_SERVICE_NAME
      - >-
        --container=frontend
      - >-
        --image=$_AR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/cloud-run-source-deploy/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME-frontend:$COMMIT_SHA
      - --port=3000
      - --depends-on=backend

However, this doesn't build because of error:
spec.template.spec.containers[0].depends_on: Dependent container 'backend' must have startup probe specified
And I don't see a way to specify the startup probe in the docs.
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/run/deploy

You cannot use gcloud [beta] run deploy
This may be (!?) because the complexity in the service configuration becomes somewhat overwhelming to define using CLI args|flags.
You will need to define your service as a Knative Service and you can then use gcloud [beta] run services replace to deploy it.
See Configuring probes
In my experience, defined Cloud Run resources using the YAML configuration is probable the better way to go and more closely mirrors Kubernetes' model.

I agree that yaml spec would feel more k8-like. However, cloudbuild.yaml configuration does NOT seem to extend/support yaml configs. It seems to only allow the limited CLI command definitions.

You would be able to check the YAML spec into your repo (another benefit). When you use Cloud Build, the repo would be materialized in the Cloud Build file system (/workspace) and you could then reference if from there ["gcloud","beta","run","services","replace","/workspace/service.yaml"]

My build starts via a Cloud Trigger (where cloudbuild.yaml is essentially pasted inline).
So you essentialyl suggest to add yaml configs right there, and reference them in the build, since they are materialized. I'll try that.

Include the Cloud Run service YAMLs in the repo that includes cloudbuild.yaml. From the Cloud Build script you can reference content from the repo in the /workspace folder including the Cloud Run service YAMLs.

The only last issue issue is that YAML spec uses a dynamic image that is based on commit SHA. So the service.yaml should be either dynamically generated, or  accept parameters?

To be specific, the cloudbuild.yaml has _AR_HOSTNAME: us-east2-docker.pkg.dev substitution that would need to be passed to the service.yaml in order to find the location of the Docker image. As an example.

This is becoming a different question and you've not yet acknowledged this one. There are many tools (sed,jq,yq,jsonnet etc.) that you can use to templatize YAML|JSON.

Appreciate your help!
